# Problems about installing FSL 6.0 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I followed the instructions on the official website:https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Linux

When I came to check the installation after I had installed it,the first check passed:
`echo $FSLDIR`
it returns
`/usr/local/fsl`

But for the second check for the right path,it failed:
`flirt -version`
it returns
`flirt: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I can still open the GUI of this software.But it seems there is something wrong with it,how should I deal with it?

Comment: Maybe this is more suited to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Maybe this is more suited to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: What does this have to do with `R`? Error message suggests that you need to install `libopenblas`.

Comment: My guess is something like `apt-get install libopenblas-base` (and/or `...-dev`) will fix your problem. Hengcheng, I'm removing the [tag:r] tag; if I'm wrong here and there really is something to do with the R programming language here, please edit your question and provide detail.

Comment: Sorry,I first came across something strange when I use a package `fslr` in r.I think that problem seems related to my installation of FSL,so I post this question here.I should add the problem background which is related  to the package `fslr`.Now the problems have been solved.Thank you so much.So grateful to you guys!!!

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the problem. Anyone who has similar problems please do `sudo apt install libopenblas-base`in your terminal. After that, when you type `flirt -version` it will return `FLIRT version 6.0`. Thank you for contributors.

Comment: Thanks. But there is a typo there, it should be 'libopenblas' - as in Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms.

Comment: I had a similar issue, on a machine where I didn't have root access (and so couldn't use the package manager). I downloaded the [source code](https://www.openblas.net/) for OpenBlas and [installed from source](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Installation-Guide) (unzip the source code directory, run `make`, and (as the output of `make` recommended), run `make PREFIX=$HOME install`; I had previously installed other libraries in my home directory), and was then able to run `flirt -version` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with FSL 6.0 initial install. The following helped to clear up the issue:

```
sudo yum install libquadmath-devel
```

The `libquadmath` can be replaced by whatever library is missing.